# Can we use a 230 V/50 Hz solenoid on a 240 V/60 Hz supply?

Tags: frequency, solenoid-valve

My question is the inverse of this one:

[Can we use 220V/60Hz Solenoid on 220V/50Hz supply?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/286176/can-we-use-220v-60hz-solenoid-on-220v-50hz-supply)

The thing is that I bought a European espresso machine rated 1450-1600 W, 220-240V, 50/60 Hz and I am planning to use it on 240 VAC at 60 Hz in Canada. I have been told other people do it.

According to the specifications it should be fine, but when I checked replacement parts for this appliance, I saw that there were 230 V, 50 Hz solenoids in it. I am surprised to see that the machine has been rated as being able to handle 240 V and 60 Hz. Will this cause premature wear?

Comment: At 60Hz current will be little bit smaller, but devises, like this, made with spare. It will work.

Answer (score -2):

Impedance increases with frequency so for a small inductor <10mH current drops when going from lower to higher frequency, but I guess the impedance of the heater is much more than 1Ω so the change in total impedance and phase shift is probably negligible.

Comment: The solenoid coil has nothing to do with the heating coil.  They are certainly not connected in any kind of way that the inductance of the heating coil should matter to the solenoid.  The solenoid would be used to open or close a valve for water or maybe to move a lever.

Comment: @JRE is correct. The solenoids in the espresso machines are valve solenoids.